# QTMovie backed by a Movie works initially, but not in another method

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, quicktime

What follows is an initializer method. It creates a Movie structure from a file, with an eye to extracting the raw pixels for processing, as per [Apple QA1443](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2005/qa1443.html). This is then wrapped in a QTMovie – `sourceMovie = [QTMovie movieWithQuickTimeMovie: ...]` – for convenience.

After initializing such an object, the second method is called, and we attempt to use `sourceMovie`. However, it turns out that **any attempt to access sourceMovie here** results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS For instance, `NSLog(@"%@", sourceMovie)` is impossible. The movie appears to have been deallocated, although it is not clear why.

Furthermore, in this second method, the usual methods to obtain a CVPixelBufferRef do not properly function: QTVisualContextIsNewImageAvailable seems always to return NO, and QTVisualContextCopyImageForTime always gives you an imageBuffer pointing at 0x00. (I guess this is not surprising if the QTMovie, Movie or visualContext are somehow being deallocated.)

The question then is, why is `sourceMovie` inaccessible from the second method? Is it being deallocated as it seems? If so, why?

And now the code, and sorry in advance for the length.

```
// From the .h, we have the following inst var declarations:
Movie                    myMovie;
QTMovie                  *sourceMovie;
QTVisualContextRef        visualContext;
CVPixelBufferRef         imageBuffer;
pixels_xy                sourceSize;
MovieAnalyzer            *analyzer;

// And now to the @implementation...

-(id)initWithFileString:(NSString *)file {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSError *e;

        // Bit of a hack - get the movie size using temporary QTMovie.
        sourceMovie = [QTMovie movieWithFile:file error:&e];
        if (e) {
            [self release];
            NSLog(@"Could not open movie.");
            return nil;
        }

        NSSize movieSize = [[sourceMovie posterImage] size];
        CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, movieSize.width, movieSize.height);

        // Save the size in pixels.
        sourceSize.x = (int)movieSize.width, sourceSize.y = (int)movieSize.height;

        CFStringRef movieLocation = (CFStringRef) file;

        // Get a QT Visual Context, and create a movie inialized to use it for output.
        visualContext = NULL;
        OSStatus status = CreatePixelBufferContext(k32ARGBPixelFormat, &bounds, &visualContext);
        if (noErr != status && NULL == visualContext) {
            [self release];
            NSLog(@"Problem initializing QT Visual Context.");
            return nil;
        }

        /*** Instantiate the Movie ***/
        myMovie = NULL;
        Boolean trueValue = true;
        QTNewMoviePropertyElement newMovieProperties[3] = {0};

        // Setup movie location
        newMovieProperties[0].propClass = kQTPropertyClass_DataLocation;
        newMovieProperties[0].propID = kQTDataLocationPropertyID_CFStringPosixPath;
        newMovieProperties[0].propValueSize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
        newMovieProperties[0].propValueAddress = &movieLocation;

        // Assign the visual context - could also be NULL
        newMovieProperties[1].propClass = kQTPropertyClass_Context;
        newMovieProperties[1].propID = kQTContextPropertyID_VisualContext;
        newMovieProperties[1].propValueSize = sizeof(visualContext);
        newMovieProperties[1].propValueAddress = &visualContext;

        // Make the movie active
        newMovieProperties[2].propClass = kQTPropertyClass_NewMovieProperty;
        newMovieProperties[2].propID = kQTNewMoviePropertyID_Active;
        newMovieProperties[2].propValueSize = sizeof(trueValue);
        newMovieProperties[2].propValueAddress = &trueValue;

        status = NewMovieFromProperties(3, newMovieProperties, 0, NULL, &myMovie);
        if (status != noErr || myMovie == NULL) {
            NSLog(@"Problem initializing theMovie"); // problem
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }

        // Create a new QTMovie with the Movie as its backing object
        sourceMovie = [QTMovie movieWithQuickTimeMovie:myMovie disposeWhenDone:NO error:&e];
        if (e) {
            NSLog(@"Could not initialize QTMovie from Movie.");
            [self release];
            return nil;
        }

        [sourceMovie stepForward];
        analyzer = [[MovieAnalyzer alloc] initWithColorString:"BGRA" andSourceSize:sourceSize];
    }
    return self;
}


-(NSImage*) supplyCalibrationImage {
    NSLog(@"%x", &sourceMovie);

    [sourceMovie stepForward];    // This fails!
    ....
}
```

Comment: You're handling the error wrong. Test whether `sourceMovie` is `nil`, not whether `e` is `nil`. The Error-Handling Guide says that a method is only guaranteed to set the error pointer on failure, not on success, nor is it guaranteed to *not* set the error pointer on success. Thus, it is possible for a method to succeed and still return an error object (possibly from a failed-but-recovered-from internal attempt).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Peter. How'd `if (sourceMovie == nil || e)` do you?

Comment: That's still wrong, because it is possible for the method you called to succeed but still return an error object. You don't want to handle an error if the message succeeded, so you should only do so if it failed.

Comment: Interesting. So, what if anything is the point in this function accepting an error pointer? I suppose it contains more info about the failure state, if we were receiving `nil`s instead of `QTMovie`s.

Comment: Ah, as per the [NSError Class Ref](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSError), *In general, a method should signal an error condition by—for example—returning NO or nil rather than by the simple presence of an error object. The method can then optionally return an NSError object by reference, in order to further describe the error.*

Comment: Benji XVI: Exactly. If it failed, you may have an error object describing the error. If it succeeded, you may or may not have an error object anyway, but you have no reason to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[QTMovie movieWithQuickTimeMovie:disposeWhenDone:error:]` is returning an autoreleased movie.  If you want it to stick around past that one method, you need to retain it.